# Copy structure with char array to char array

Tags: c++

I have a problem as the topic.

My code:

```
struct message{
    char sender_name[20];
    char dest_name[20];
    char content_message[256];
};

int main() {
message tmp;

printf("Enter your name\n");
std::cin>>tmp.sender_name;

printf("Enter dest name\n");
std::cin>>tmp.dest_name;

printf("Enter message to %s \n",tmp.dest_name);
std::cin>>tmp.content_message;

memcpy(&buffer, &tmp,sizeof(tmp));

printf("MEASAGE: %s\n",buffer);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In buffer is only tmp.sendername and I don't know how to fix it. 
I read a lot of topics but I can't fix it.

Please for help.

Comment: What is `buffer`?

Comment: Why do you believe that `printf("MEASAGE: %s\n",buffer);` would print your message in a structured way?? It will stop at the 1st encountered `'\0'` character.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The %s in your  printf statement means " the first of the following parameter is a char*". It actually is a message, and just by case it's address is the same of it's first member, a char*. This code has undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

It copies everything, you're just accessing it wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
struct message{
    char sender_name[20];
    char dest_name[20];
    char content_message[256];
};
char buffer[sizeof(message)];

int main() {
    message tmp;

    printf("Enter your name\n");
    std::cin>>tmp.sender_name;

    printf("Enter dest name\n");
    std::cin>>tmp.dest_name;

    printf("Enter message to %s \n",tmp.dest_name);
    std::cin>>tmp.content_message;

    memcpy(&buffer, &tmp,sizeof(tmp));

    message *cpy = reinterpret_cast<message*>(buffer);
    printf(
        "sender_name: '%s\n'"
        "dest_name: '%s\n'"
        "content_message: '%s\n'",
        cpy->sender_name,
        cpy->dest_name,
        cpy->content_message
    );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Test:

```
g++ buffer.cc && printf '%s\n' foo bar baz | ./a.out
```

Output:

```
Enter your name
Enter dest name
Enter message to bar 
sender_name: 'foo
'dest_name: 'bar
'content_message: 'baz
'
```

Also, BTW, probably not a good way to read into char buffers. There can hardly be any range checking with this API (given that it also appears to work with pointers as opposed to just arrays) which would make it about as unsafe as `gets`. It also doesn't appear to be documented (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) and out of gcc and clang, only gcc accepts it.

Comment: wrong cppreference page: operator>> to char pointers is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2 and it uses [std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to range-check